# Access Violation in WINE

Tags: 12.04, wine, winetricks

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and wine version 1.5. Whenever I am trying to install [boxoft pdf to flash converter](http://www.boxoft.com/pdf-to-flash/) it gives an error of -

> access violation at address 00409A0E. Write of Address 00400000.

What to do to install this. Is it that some dll is missing or something. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `Wine 1.5.19` (the development version) and it does install successfully when I used XP as the Windows version.

However, you may be interested to know that there is a native program that will probably do what you want. It is the `pdf2swf` module in the [swf tools](http://www.swftools.org/download.html) suite of programs. It does need to be compiled, but it is relatively straightforward to do so. For those on 12.10 and above, it is [in the repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/swftools) once more, but the package unfortunately does not include `pdf2swf` or `avi2swf`, as shown [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/i386/swftools/filelist).

**Compilation**

Compilation should be pretty straightforward, as [noted here](http://wiki.swftools.org/wiki/Installation), but here is how I did it.

You can use the git repository with `git clone git://git.swftools.org/swftools`, but it is probably better to use the stable source code, so download [the package](http://www.swftools.org/swftools-0.9.2.tar.gz), and open terminal and `cd` to the download folder and extract it with

```
tar xzvf swftools-0.9.2.tar.gz
```

You need to download some tools and dependencies, so please enter the following:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall libgif-dev libjpeg8-dev libfreetype6-dev
```

Now, with terminal `cd` to the unpacked `swftools-0.9.2` folder and simply run

```
./configure && make
```

and then

```
sudo checkinstall
```

The programs in the suite will now be available for you; enter `pdf2swf` for a list of options, and to convert a pdf to swf with no particular options, run

```
pdf2swf my.pdf -o new_version.swf
```

You may have some particular requirements, so I should take a look at the various command switches.

You can then open the swf file in the viewer that you use, or even use your web browser to check that it is a valid file (if you have flash installed).

More information on the suite of tools is available at [the official site](http://wiki.swftools.org/wiki/Main_Page), which details options for all of the programs.

Comment: i am stuck at the make part it is giving
`make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

Comment: ok i figured it out `./configure` :D. Many Many Many Many Thanks to you friend.

Comment: @ArinChakraborty Sorry, I forgot to add the `./configure` part- I'll edit my answer!

Comment: Another question - I noticed that the file generated with pdf2swf is smaller by 50kb. Why so ? Is it more efficient then the one i used. I am telling so because i experienced lot more usability with opensource. Or something wrong ? Thanks again !

Comment: @ArinChakraborty I'm not sure why it should be smaller- probably just the different way the files are processed- all the files I generated came out fine, so it shouldn't be a problem with the program. You can enter `pdf2swf` for a list of options- the default setting for the quality of jpeg images is 85 and this can be increased to 100; this could account for differences if the other application is using a higher quality setting.